# How to Put using tftpd32 utility

Tags: linux, windows, get, put, tftp

I want to send and receive files from TMS320DM365 device which runs Linux to a Windows 7 (32-bit) PC. For my setup, the device is TFTP server and PC is TFTP client.

I use tftpd32 utilty.http://www.jounin.net/tftpd32_download.html

While I am able to successfully receive i.e. GET from the Linux target to Windows PC, I am unable to send anything or PUT from Windows PC to Linux target, and obtain an error:-

"Server stops the transfer Error#0: Permission Denied"

How can this be solved? Can you help me?

Thanks!

Comment: You have not given any details as to how the server is running on your board. The reasons for the failure are many. server not running with put enabled. selinux denying writes.

Comment: Thank you @Petesh, I have installed a tftp server client debian ARM version on the board. It is run from /usr/sbin directory on the target device.